# Add texture to QT OpenGL scene graph

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, qml

I am trying to render a texture to a simple opengl square. I just want to map the texture directly onto the rectangle. I followed the scene graph example, located [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html), on how to call opengl functions and display shapes, but i'm lost with trying to add a texture. I checked through multiple docs and they all dealt with using the fixed function pipeline, or subclassing QGLWidget. I would like to keep this example OpenGL ES and with utilizing shaders.

I am new to OpenGL so if anyone could give me an understanding of what has to happen, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render a texture in a [Frame Buffer Object](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickframebufferobject.html) and then display it in the scene graph. See the [Scene Graph - Rendering FBOs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinsgnode-example.html) example.

Comment: https://conf.qtcon.org/system/attachments/137/original/writing-custom-qtquickcomponents-QtCon.pdf%3F1473164662